# Matrix with elements in $L^\infty(0,T)$ means inverse matrix also has elements in $L^\infty(0,T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Let $A(t)$ be a matrix with entries $a_{ij} \in L^\infty(0,T)$.

Suppose $A(t)^{-1}$ exists, and is positive-definite. Does it follow that $A(t)^{-1}$ has elements in $L^\infty(0,T)$ too?

Comment: Consider the one-dimensional case...